# EXT3 file system pre digest material

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, ext3

I am looking for understanding EXT3 filesystem source code. I think I need a little pre-digestion  to fully understand the code. Can anyone please suggest some material(blog etc.) where I can get some basic understanding of the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this paper on ext3](http://original.jamesthornton.com/hotlist/linux-filesystems/ext3-journal-design.pdf) mostly about "why". Get general overview about [linux filesystems](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-filesystem/) and read [ext3 documentation in linux kernel code](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37.2/Documentation/filesystems/ext3.txt).

This should get you a good understanding about the code.